# Displays a message in the wrong order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, chat, vaadin

I created vaadin chat, and I need that when any user enters the chat, he should see only the last 10 messages from MySQL database. I think my code is implemented incorrectly. Because it shows me the first 10 messages, although the program should show the last 10 messages.

My code
MainView class -

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    private final MessagesInfoManager messagesInfoManager;
    private final RestService restService;
    private String username;
    private TextField textField;
    private Message messageLast;


    @Autowired
    public MainView(RestService restService) {
        this.messagesInfoManager = MessageConfigurator.getInstance().getChatMessagesInfoManager();
        addClassName("main-view");
        setSizeFull();
        setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);

        H1 header = new H1("Vaadin Chat");
        header.getElement().getThemeList().add("dark");

        add(header);

        askUsername();
        this.restService = restService;
    }

    private void askUsername() {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        TextField usernameField = new TextField();
        Button startButton = new Button("Start chat");

        layout.add(usernameField, startButton);

        startButton.addClickListener(click -> {
            username = usernameField.getValue();
            remove(layout);
            showChat(username);
        });

        add(layout);
    }

    private void showChat(String username) {
        MessageList messageList = new MessageList();

        List<Message> lasts = restService.getLast();
        for (Message message : lasts) {
            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.getFromV() + ": " + message.getMessageV()));
        }

        messageLast = lasts.get(lasts.size() - 1);

        add(messageList, createInputLayout(username, messageList));
        expand(messageList);
    }

    private Component createInputLayout(String username, MessageList messageList) {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        layout.setWidth("100%");

        TextField messageField = new TextField();
        messageField.addKeyDownListener(Key.ENTER, keyDownEvent -> sender(messageField, messageList));
        Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
        sendButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);

        layout.add(messageField, sendButton);
        layout.expand(messageField);

        messageField.addFocusListener(event -> {
            for (Message message : messagesInfoManager.getMessagesByUI(getUI())) {
                if (!message.getFromV().equals(username)) {
                    message.setUnread(false);
                    this.restService.updateMessage(message.getId(), message);
                }
            }
        });

        sendButton.addClickListener(click -> sender(messageField, messageList));
        messageField.focus();

        return layout;
    }

    private void sender(TextField textField, MessageList messageList) {
        Message message = new Message(username, textField.getValue());
        message = restService.saveMessage(message);
        messageLast = message;
        this.textField = textField;
        messagesInfoManager.updateMessageUIInfo(new MessageInfo(messageList, message, this));
        textField.clear();
        textField.focus();

    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {

        MessageList messageList = new MessageList();

        List<LinkedHashMap> lasts = restService.getUnreadMessages(messageLast.getId());

        for (LinkedHashMap message : lasts) {
            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.get("fromV") + ": " + message.get("messageV")));
        }

        messagesInfoManager.updateMessageUIInfo(new MessageInfo(messageList, messageLast, this));

    }

}
```

I have api/last  - Which should display the last 10 messages

```
 @GetMapping("/api/last")
    public List<Message> getLasts() {
        return (messageService.getLast());
    }
```

MessageRepository i have SQL query for last 10 messages

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM chatMessages LIMIT 10", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> getLastMessages();
```

My Github
https://github.com/adk96/vaadin-chat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL queries are sorted in ascending order by default. You need to set your query to sort in descending order.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM chatMessages ORDER BY <yourFieldName> DESC LIMIT 10", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> getLastMessages();
```

Answer (score 2):

To return the last 10 records, you can use something like this:

In **MessageRepository** change:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM chatMessages LIMIT 10", nativeQuery = true)
List<Message> getLastMessages();
```

To

```
Page<Message> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

In **MessageServiceImpl** change:

```
@Override
public List<Message> getLast() {
    return repository.getLastMessages();
}
```

To

```
@Override
public List<Message> getLast() {
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.Direction.DESC, "time");
    Page<Message> bottomPage = repository.findAll(pageable);
    return bottomPage.getContent();
}
```

Comment: I definitely need to do it through SQL query

Comment: This is certainly a way to achieve your needs. If you need to do it through SQL query, you should have stated so in the question. If you knew you had to do it by changing your SQL, why did you include java, vaadin, spring, chat in the question in the first place? You could've just asked how to order by a timestamp field in sql.